# ng-filter by string tokens of input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have multiple input fields that I am currently filtering a `ng-repeat` by like so

```
...
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="itemFilter.id" /> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="itemFilter.attr1" /> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="itemFilter.attr2" /> 
 ...
<tr ng-repeat="item in $scope.items | filter:itemFilter | orderBy: '-id'  track by $index"> <td>{{item.id}}</td>
</tr>
 ...
```

How can I filter on the tokens from each the inputs?

For example, if `itemFilter.id` = `"1 2 3"` the `ng-repeat` would include ids that contain 1,2, or 3

Comment: removing tagging of angular as its only a angularjs question

Comment: in your "filter" you simply pass in the accepted values, you'd then need to make sure your custom filter takes in the 2 parameters (input,params) loop through your input list and match all items for params you can use array.protoype.filter [mdn filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you have a transpiler.

Comment: @eli were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrei mentioned, you have to write your own [custom `filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) to achieve the desired functionality. The code below illustrates how it could be created and how the parameters could be passed to perform custom filtering logic.

The idea here is to build an array of tokens for each object property using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and then check if item satisfy the filters using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on filters array:

```js
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("demo", [])
        .filter("filterByTokens", function () {
            return function (items, obj) {
                var separator = obj.separator || ' ';
                var keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (key) {
                    return key !== 'separator'
                });
                //create filters array
                var filters = keys.map(function (key) {
                    return {
                        key: key,
                        values: (obj[key] || '').split(separator).filter(function (val) {
                            return !!val;
                        })
                    }
                });

                if (!filters.length) return items;

                return items.filter(function (item) {
                    return filters.filter(function (f) {
                        return !f.values || !f.values.length || (f.values.indexOf(item[f.key].toString()) > -1);
                    }).length === filters.length; // we want to check if all filters are satisfied
                });
            };
        })
        .controller('Demo', [function Demo() {
            var vm = this;

            vm.itemFilter = {id:'1 3 5 2 6', name: 'Test5 Test6', separator: ' '};

            vm.items = [
                {id: 1, name: 'Test1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Test2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Test3'},
                {id: 4, name: 'Test4'}, {id: 5, name: 'Test5'}, {id: 6, name: 'Test6'},
            ];
        }]);

})(angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="Demo as vm">     
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="vm.itemFilter.id" placeholder="itemFilter.ids"/> 
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="vm.itemFilter.name" placeholder="vm.itemFilter.names"/> 
  <hr/>
  <code>Filter: {{vm.itemFilter}}</code>
  <hr/>
  <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filterByTokens:vm.itemFilter | orderBy: '-id'  track by item.id"> 
    <span>
      {{item.id}}
    </span>
    <span>
      {{item.name}}
    </span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

P.S.: Possibly not the most performant solution, but just a demonstration of how this could be achieved using [`filters`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).